# JQuery-UI draggable reset to original position

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

This is probably very easy to do, but I always think too complicated.

I've just set up a simple test with #draggable / #droppable with a fixed width/height + float:left.

I then want a reset button to be able to reset the #draggable to it's original state after it's been snapped to a #droppable. (bottom line)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#draggable").draggable
    ({  
        revert: 'invalid',
        snap: '#droppable',
        snapMode: 'corner',
        snapTolerance: '22'

    });
});

    $("#droppable").droppable
    ({
        accept: '#draggable', 
        drop: function(event, ui) 
        {
            $(this).find("#draggable").html();
        }
});

    $(".reset").click(function() {
    /* What do I put here to reset the #draggable to it's original position before the snap */
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Draggable items don't keep track of their original position that I know of; only during drag and to be snapped back.  You can just do this on your own, though:

```
$("#draggable").data({
    'originalLeft': $("#draggable").css('left'),
    'origionalTop': $("#draggable").css('top')
});

$(".reset").click(function() {
    $("#draggable").css({
        'left': $("#draggable").data('originalLeft'),
        'top': $("#draggable").data('origionalTop')
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/wSLJC/

Comment: Seems to be what I need. However, when I add  $("#draggable").data({'originalLeft': $("#draggable").css('left'),
                      'origionalTop': $("#draggable").css('top')
                     });

The draggable stops working

Comment: @user2110966 I think your comment is incomplete?

Comment: I edited it, sorry about that. "The draggable stops working".
I even tried to just copy/paste the entire thing. That's weird, as it clearly works on the demo.

Comment: @user2110966 hard to say without seeing the rest of your code / website

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6TNeZ/3/  that's basically it.. Tried looking for errors, but couldn't find any.

Comment: I see an error; you were not closing the string on `'#droppable`: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/6TNeZ/4/

Comment: Oh.. Now I feel stupid. Thanks a lot for your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 21):

I used this on a project

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
    $(".draggable-item").animate({
        top: "0px",
        left: "0px"
    });
});
```

did the trick for me

Comment: I used a combination of this and getting the original coordinates from the other answer rather than setting it back to 0,0.

Comment: this is excellent for none absolute positions looks real nice to!

Answer (score 8):

I've just had great success with the following:

```
$(".draggable-item").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: This answer did help me, but it also removes the 'position: relative', causing the next drag action to not animate in the original way.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the following was the simplest way to reset to original position, but if you want the item to remain draggle this will not work alone

```
$(".draggable-item").removeAttr('style');
```

This worked for me to reset to original position and keep item draggable:

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
    // Reset position
    $(".draggable-item").removeAttr('style');

    // Destroy original draggable and create new one
    $(".draggable-item").draggable("destroy");
    $(".draggable-item").draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used h0dges' basic idea. The balls I created returned to their original positions, but I lost the styles that made them into balls. Therefore, I kept the styles of the balls and just reset their top and left styles to return them to their original positions:

```
function endRound() {
   $(".ball").css({"top":"", "left":""});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what people wish to see but I have made a fiddle about resetting objects to initial positions on a single click either vertical or horizontal.`Fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/JunaidAli/wp1n796q/321/